# Grafana charts pointing to influx database on the fly

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I have a influxdb setup with multiple databases where each database has similar measurements. I'd like to create a generic dashboard where user can select the database, measurement on the fly as a variable.

select blah from **"$database"."autogen"."$measurement"** where yada yada

i do not want to duplicate n different dashboards for each databse, is there a way to select database on the fly in the query itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Grafana does not allow you to switch between databases, it has to be selected first when specifying queries and only one database is an option currently which cannot be parameterized

Answer (score -1):

when you create your query use `show databases` for getting databases. I test this in grafana v5.2.2. (set a data source of your database for data source for run this query)